# Html, javascript and InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a div with an innerHTML on a other html page. a little schema is better than 10 words (probably)

```
---------------------------------
|Page1                           |
|       -----------              |
|       |Page2    |              |
|       |         |              |
|       |         |              |
|       -----------              |
|                                |
---------------------------------
```

Here, Page1 is my main page, and Page2 is my InnerHTML.
In page2 I have a map of lots of points, with hyperlink.

If I open Page2 Directly, I can click on those hyperlinks, and the XML file open.
But if I open Page1 (then Page2 is here too) and click on hyperlinks, my browser bug, and doesn't open anything.

Little code for those who wants  to help me:
page 1 code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>mouseover image position</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body
{
    background-color:#aaaaff;
}
#one
{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
height:100%;
}
object
{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:solid 1px #000000;
}
 /*//]]>*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// written by: Coothead
function updateObjectIframe(which){
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo"     name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="SiteMap.htm"></object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and page 2 :

```js
function startDrag(e) {
            // determine event object
            if (!e) {
            var e = window.event;
        }

        // IE uses srcElement, others use target
        var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    //alert(targ.height);
        maxsizeX = targ.width;
        maxsizeY = targ.height;

        //alert(maxsizeX + " " + maxsizeY);

        if (targ.className != 'dragme') {return};
        // calculate event X, Y coordinates
            offsetX = e.clientX;
            offsetY = e.clientY;

        // assign default values for top and left properties
        if(!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left='0px'};
        if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top='0px'};


        // calculate integer values for top and left 
        // properties
        coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
        coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
        drag = true;

        // move div element
            document.onmousemove=dragDiv;

    }
    function dragDiv(e) {
        if (!drag) {return};
        if (!e) { var e= window.event};
        var img = "SiteMap.png";
        var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
        // move div element
            if (coordX+e.clientX-offsetX < 0 && coordX+e.clientX-offsetX > -maxsizeX+500){
                targ.style.left=coordX+e.clientX-offsetX+'px';
            }
            if (coordY+e.clientY-offsetY< 0 && coordY+e.clientY-offsetY > -maxsizeY+500){
                targ.style.top=coordY+e.clientY-offsetY+'px';
            }
        return false;
    }
    function stopDrag() {
        drag=false;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        document.onmousedown = startDrag;
        document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Site Map</title>

<style type="text/css">
.dragme {
    position:relative;
    cursor: move;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="SiteMap.png" border=0 usemap="#TruView"  id="draggable" class="dragme">
<map name="TruView">

<area title="P96N-P-1" shape="circle" coords="808,476,8" href="P96N-P-1/TruView.xml">
<area title="P96N-P-2" shape="circle" coords="874,882,8" href="P96N-P-2/TruView.xml">
<area title="P96N-P-3" shape="circle" coords="924,1424,8" href="P96N-P-3/TruView.xml">
<area title="P96N-P-4" shape="circle" coords="978,1781,8" href="P96N-P-4/TruView.xml">
<area title="P604-P-1" shape="circle" coords="947,2140,8" href="P604-P-1/TruView.xml">
...
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone can help me, I take everything! Thanks a lot!
Have a nice evening!

Edit : I work with an IE add-on, so it's IE :/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the inner page in an `<object>` and not an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Can you post the console's error message?

Comment: Because i'm bad with HTML, and this is probably not the best solution I can find :) But I take all propositions!
When I click on hyperlink, nothing open (the current page close, and I have only the backfont of the page remaining. I can still use the "go back one page" button) and when i close the browser (only when i close it, even if I clicked on the hyperlink then come back on the mainpage) I have the box "IE has stop running".

Comment: Do you really want the image map to be draggable? What exactly is the purpose of the JS code in page 2?

Comment: I want the image to be draggable, it is the purpose of my work in fact.
The JS permit me to drag the image in the div, and stop it when the image is out of the div. In fact, i want to be able to drag an image that is larger than the div (A little like googleMap if you consider the map as a big big image) (but here, it's only the beginning, I have to improve all of it)

Comment: Edit : It works if I use shift+click instead of just a click (if I open the hyperlink in a new windows, it works fine)...

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/ Please validate your html.

Comment: It says that I have tons of error!
What does it do?